# How to get devenv.exe to display its output on the console

Tags: visual-c++

I'm using devenv /Rebuild  but there's no output written to the console. That's annoying since I want to keep track of progress.

If I use /out log.txt then it writes to the "log.txt" which, of course, I can inspect after the build.

Perhaps there's some symbol foo that stands for the console so I could write /out foo?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can't.

But you **can** use `devenv.com` rather than `devenv.exe` (it's in the same directory). The former *does* write to the console, even if you use `/out` to write to a log file.

The command line arguments are identical.